# Highcharts - Seeing Extra Lines on Secondary Y-Axis

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

So, i had a doubt regarding reducing the lines, or keeping the secondary y-axis in high charts. I have more than three sets of data being plotted. Please find the following image.

[image]

Comment: Without seeing your actual code this is just a guess. Set min/max on this yAxis, set tickmark intervals, then take a look at `http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.alignTicks`.

Comment: Or just hide the gridlines on the secondary axis.